# Deleting tenant in wso2is 5.11 using REST API

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

When trying to delete a tenant I am getting error

> Tenant deletion property Tenant.TenantDelete is not enabled in carbon.xml file.

I added the following to deployment.toml

```
[Tenant]
TenantDelete=true
ListenerInvocationPolicy.InvokeOnDelete=false
```

Because modifying carbon.xml's TenantDelete property was not being persisted. Still, after applying these changes I am getting the same error during delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the following config into the deployment.toml file and restart the server. Then check whether  `<TenantDelete>true</TenantDelete>` is set in the carbon.xml file.

```
[tenant_mgt]
tenant_deletion=true
```

The config you have added won't change the property in `carbon.xml`. Refer to `carbon.xml.j2` to understand the templated configuration. Also, refer to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BRWvtcV1T94&feature=youtu.be) to understand configuration chnages via deployment.toml.